# JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.setLong throws java.sql.SQLException: Optional feature not implemented

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a problem with long numbers in prepared statement. Here is the code:

```
String removeCltQry = "DELETE * FROM Clients WHERE client_id = ?";
long client_id = 10;
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement pstm = null;

try {
    con = DBMngerST.instance().getDBCon();
    pstm = con.prepareStatement(removeCltQry);
    pstm.setLong(1, client_id);
    pstm.executeUpdate();
    pstm.close();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (con != null) {
        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]Optional feature not implemented
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLBindInParameterBigint(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.setLong(Unknown Source)
at testingPack.test5.main(test5.java:25)
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: And exactly, what JDBC driver are you using? which version?

Comment: It appears to be saying that the MS version of `setLong` isn't implemented.  Have you tried `setInt(1, (int)client_id)`?  Can you really have a `client_id` value larger that 2 billion?

Comment: Yes i tried  setInt, setString and evrething is ok. But the problem is in setLong...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I can understand, "Optional feature not implemented" typically happens if there is a mismatch between the ODBC driver's capabilities and the JDBC-ODBC bridge's expectations.  In this case, it looks like there is a mismatch between the `setLong` call and effective data type that is being used on the Access side.

My advice would be to check that the MS Access / ODBC type you are using is truly compatible with `long`; i.e. that all theoretically representable values are representable as Java `long` values.  If changing the schema doesn't work, then your best bet is to treat the number as an `int` or `String` from the Java / JDBC side.

(Bear in mind that you are using MS Access which isn't a "real" database, and that the MS Access ODBC drivers could have functionality limitations.  It is also worth checking for new versions of the drivers and the bridge libraries.)

Answer (score 0):

I want to know what the version is of your Java. It seems that this exception is caused by the absence implementation of setLong in the PrepareStatement class.

Moreover, it may be a bug caused by the old implementation.
You can see some comments in the method of setLong, just refer to here[enter link description here](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/sun/jdbc/odbc/JdbcOdbcPreparedStatement.java.html).

Answer (score -3):

Try putting the id right in the query, something like this.

```
String removeCltQry = "DELETE * FROM Clients WHERE client_id = 10";

long client_id = 10;

Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement pstm = null;

try {
con = DBMngerST.instance().getDBCon();
pstm = con.prepareStatement(removeCltQry);

//pstm.setLong(1, client_id);
pstm.executeUpdate();
pstm.close();


} catch (SQLException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  if (con != null) {
    try {
       con.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
 }// finally
```

Comment: That might be OK for debugging purposes, but is such a bad, bad practice building queries with wired parameters!

Comment: Well, it would be OK if the user's code really has `client_id` hard-coded like that.  But I assume that's just scaffolding.

Comment: Thanks Robert, but i need it in Prepared Statement... And in this way i have a problem.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I agree that's not good practice but as Hot Licks points out it's basically a wire parameter and secondly at this point it is a debugging thing in order to figure out what's going on.  I wouldn't recommend this for a permanent solution.